# Is Qt Model/View programming design pattern limited?

Tags: qt, design-patterns, view, model

I'm reading about [Model/View programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) design pattern but I don't understand how to define a model. My model should inherit from QAbstractItemModel? If yes, I think it is very limited because my models class couldn't inherit from another model class.

Comment: Strictly speaking there's no real need to inherit from another class. Usually, [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) is [prefered over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: The problem is that I'm using ActiveRecord as ORM so all model class in my app inherit from ActiveRecord::Base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has multiple inheritance, so technically your models *could* derive both from the Qt model base classes and something else.
That being said, multiple inheritance is rather tricky (for me anyway), composition is easier to get right.

One way of "merging" your ORM model classes with Qt's is to create a Qt model class that has one (or more) of your ORM's models as a member. The Qt model would essentially proxy all requests to your ORM model. The Qt model would be just an "adapter". This keeps your ORM code independent from the GUI toolkit, which is generally good.

Make sure you check out the [Model subclassing reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference) for the Qt side of things.